# Parsing multiple CSV files in bash by pattern with counter

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix, awk

Let's assume I have the files

- report-x-1.csv
- report-x-2.csv
- report-x-3.csv
- report-y-1.csv
- report-y-2.csv
- report-y-3.csv

I get the last value of second column with a little formatting

```
 awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print "x:";print want} ' report-x-1.csv >> test.txt
```

How do I do this with any number of .csv files and have a counter on top?

```
awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print "x:";print want} ' report-x-* >> test.txt
```

is only doing something for the first file.

What I need in the end is a .csv like this but with any number of inputfile:

```
x1 , 300
x2 , 250
x3 , 300
y1 , 270
y2 , 250
y3 , 280
```

**EDIT:**
I have not yet tried every idea in detail, to make it clearer here are two example files

https://pastebin.com/VMb32ULc

https://pastebin.com/qXQnagQ9

These files are could be named report-x-1.csv and report-y-1.csv and the output file should contain two lines x-1: 156. ... and y-1: 300. .... (which is the last line  second column)
The solution should work with multiple input files like mentioned above.

Comment: `if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}` it looks like you want the maximum value, not the last value.

Comment: @blackbaddl : The default field separator for awk is a space, so - if I take your example file - a `echo 'x1 , 300' | awk '{print $2}'` would output a comma, not the number in the 2nd CSV column.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes you are right, but the first column is a rising counter anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Since no samples are given so couldn't test it. But this should be faster than a `for` loop which traverse through all csv files and calls `awk` in each iteration.

***Following are the points taken care in this program:***

- NO need to use a `for` loop to traverse through `.csv` files, since `awk` is capable of it.
- OP's code is NOT taking care of getting `x`, `y` values from file names I have added that logic too.
- One could setup the output file name in `BEGIN` section of code as per need too.

---

---

```
awk -v max=0 '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" , "
  output_file="output.txt"
}
FNR==1{
  if(want){
    print output":"ORS want > (output_file)    
  }
  split(FILENAME,array,"[-.]")
  output=array[2] array[3]
  want=max=""
}
{
  if($1>max){
    want=$2
    max=$1
  }
}
END{
  print output":"ORS want > (output_file)
}
' *.csv
```

Typo fixed by OP

Answer (score 2):

Maybe trying something like:

```sh
for file in $(ls)
do
    echo 'Doing something to file:' $file
    awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print "x:";print want} ' $file >> test.txt
done
```

Or maybe:

```sh
for file in $(ls)
do
    if [[ $file == *.csv ]]; then
        echo 'Doing something to file:' $file
        awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print "x:";print want} ' $file >> test.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: [Why not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) and `for file in $(ls)` will break if there are any whitespaces and other characters in the filenames and the unquoted `$file` can lead to bugs. Just use globbing `for file in *` and quote your variables. `for file in $(ls)
do
    if [[ $file == *.csv ]];` why not `for i in *.csv` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

To run a script for each file in a directory you can use pipep the filenames and use `xargs -n1` :

```
echo report-x-*.csv | xargs -n1 awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print "x:";print want}' >> test.txt
```